# How to save .xls data received from http request to file as a in node.js

Tags: node.js, xls, fs

I want to create an XLS file using data received from the HTTP request.
I tried saving it using FS.writeFile() but no luck.

I am using request npm module to execute HTTP request:

```
request(url, function(err, res, data) {
    if(err || res.statusCode !== 200) return;
    fs.writeFileSync('test.xls', data);
});
```

Response:

```
 {
          "headers": {
            "content-type": "application/vnd.ms-excel",
            "transfer-encoding": "chunked",
            "connection": "close",
            "content-disposition": "attachment;filename=\"Detail_Tally.xls\"",
            "cache-control": "max-age=0",
            "x-content-type-options": "nosniff"
          },
          "request": {
            "uri": {
              "protocol": "https:",
              "slashes": true,
              "auth": null,
              "host": "testserver.com",
              "port": 443,
              "hostname": "testserver.com",
              "hash": null,
              "search": null,
              "query": null,
              "pathname": "/report/exportExcel",
              "path": "/report/exportExcel",
              "href": "https://testserver.com/report/exportExcel"
            },
            "method": "POST",
            "headers": {
              "content-type": "multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------896095632834245509104518",
              "content-length": 1393
            }
          }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It worked after setting the encoding option to null

```
request(url, {encoding: null}, function(err, res, data) {
    if(err || res.statusCode !== 200) return;
    fs.writeFileSync('test.xls', data);
});
```